# Как из $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] получить переменную?

Tags: php

`$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` содержит `"https://domain.com/?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4"`. Как получить значение переменной `b`?

Comment: Например, с помощью [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$serv = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
parse_str($serv, $output);
echo $output['b'];
```